# Webclient 404 protocol error on valid url c#

Tags: c#, webclient, http-error

I have a `webclient` that calls to a `URL` that works fine when i view it in a browser, which led me to believe i would need to add headers in to my call

I have done this, but am still getting the error.

I do have other calls to the same API that work fine, and have checked that all the parameters I am passing across are exactly the same as expected(case, spelling)

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.Proxy = proxy;
    wb.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
    wb.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
    wb.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"); 
    byte[] response = wb.UploadValues("http://myserver/api/account/GetUser",
                                      new NameValueCollection()
                                      {
                                          { "email", register.Email },
                                      });
    userDetails = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am still getting the protocol error on a call that works perfectly fine in a browser?

Comment: Please publish the exact error.

Comment: all i am getting is a 404 not found, and when i open the details all it says is ProtocolError

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to compare the webclient with your code.  Error 404 can mean a lot of different things.  To prevent hackers from entering websites, often 404 is always returned when a failure occurs and doesn't give exact cause of failure.

Comment: Just to make sure, replace `" en-US"` with `"en-US"`. Does `GetUser` function expects a GET or a POST http operation?

Comment: Is the proxy correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UploadValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) uses a HTTP POST. Are you sure that it what you want? If you are viewing it in a browser it is likely a GET, unless you are filling out some sort of web form.

One might surmise that what you are trying to do is GET this response "http://myserver/api/account/GetUser?email=blah@blah.com"

in which case you would just formulate that url, with query parameters, and execute a GET using one of the [DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    wb.Proxy = proxy;
    userDetails = wb.DownloadString("http://myserver/api/account/GetUser?email=" + register.Email);
}
```

[The Wikipedia article on REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) has a nice table that outlines the semantics of each HTTP verb, which may help choosing the appropriate `WebClient` method to use for your use cases.